# How to write test class for batch in salesforce

Tags: unit-test, batch, code-coverage, schedulebatch

I have a Batch like this, how to write test class coverage 100% for it. Please help me, thanks

public class StoreWorkTimeBatch2 implements Database.Batchable{

```
     public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {        
 
        BatchSetting__c customsetting = BatchSetting__c.getOrgDefaults();
        // ko get customsetting or date = null
        if(String.isBlank(customsetting.Id) || customsetting.RunBatchDate__c == null){
            return Database.getQueryLocator('SELECT id  FROM Store__c limit 0');
        }
        //tao start date
        Date startDate = customsetting.RunBatchDate__c.addMonths(1).toStartOfMonth().addDays(-1);
        //tao end date
        Date endDate = customsetting.RunBatchDate__c.addMonths(2).toStartOfMonth().addDays(-1);
        //
        return Database.getQueryLocator('SELECT id, Contact__c, Account__c, WorkTime__c FROM Store__c WHERE StartDate__c >= startDate AND EndDate__c <= endDate');
    }
    // comment vào
    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<Store__c> storeList){
        //tao set account
        Set<String> accountIdSet = new Set<String>();
        //tao set contact
        Set<String> contactIdSet = new Set<String>();
        //tao map
        Map<String, List<Store__c>> storeMap = new Map<String, List<Store__c>>();
        //
        for(Store__c store : storeList){
            //kiem tra khong null thì add vao
            if(String.isNotBlank(store.Account__c)){
                accountIdSet.add(store.Account__c);
            }
            //kiem tra null khong null thì add vao
            if(String.isNotBlank(store.Contact__c)){
                contactIdSet.add(store.Contact__c);
            }
            //kiem tra khong null thì tao key
            if(String.isNotBlank(store.Account__c) && String.isNotBlank(store.Contact__c)){
                //tao key
                String key = String.valueOf(store.Account__c) + String.valueOf(store.Contact__c);
                //trung key thi add vao list
                if(storeMap.containsKey(key)){
                    storeMap.get(key).add(store);
                }else{
                //khong trung key thi tạo moi
                    storeMap.put(key, new List<Store__c>{store});
                }
            }
        }
        
        // tao list AggregateResult
        List<AggregateResult> workTimeList = new List<AggregateResult>();
        //get
        workTimeList = [SELECT Account__c,
                        Contact__c,
                        SUM(WorkTime__c) TotalWorktime 
                    FROM Work__c 
                    WHERE Account__c IN :accountIdSet
                    AND Contact__c IN :contactIdSet 
                    GROUP BY Account__c, Contact__c];
        
        //  
        List<Store__c> storeUpdateList = new List<Store__c>();
        for(AggregateResult result  : workTimeList){
            //
            String key = String.valueOf(result.get('Account__c')) + String.valueOf(result.get('Contact__c'));
            //truong hop trung key
            if(storeMap.containsKey(key)){
                //add vao list
                for(Store__c store : storeMap.get(key)){
                    store.WorkTime__c = (Decimal) result.get('TotalWorktime');
                    storeUpdateList.add(store);
                }
                
            }
        }
        //truong hop khac null thi update
        if(!storeUpdateList.isEmpty()){
            update storeUpdateList;
        }
        
        System.Debug('Update Succeed');
    }
    
    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc){
    
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I need detailed code

Comment: This site isn't a place to get your code (or tests) written for free. You need to put work into doing it yourself first. This site works best when you have a narrow and specific question and can show us what you've tried.

Comment: welcome to SFSE!  Please see [ask] on getting the most from the Community. - we're not a code-writing service. There are plenty of examples on stackexchange of test methods for batchables

Comment: Can you give me some code hints about my batch test class, please